# Generating standard errors in poLCA function

Tags: r, class, analysis, standard-error

I am using the poLCA function in R. I am wondering if there is a way to generate standard errors (along with probabilities) using this function?

So far, I have tried using the arguments prob.se and P.se I believe, but I wasn't able to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.